# How do I fix "undefined reference to _gfortran_set_std" errors when compiling a simple Fortran program?

Tags: gcc, gfortran

I'm trying to compile a simple Fortran program, called `sandbox.for`:

```
program sandbox
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
    real(dp), dimension(2, 2) :: a
    integer :: i

    a = reshape([1, 2, 1, 2], shape(a))
    do i=1,2
        print *, a(i, :)
    end do

end program sandbox
```

I attempted to compile the program using `gfortran -ffree-form -o sandbox sandbox.for`, but I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccylnLGH.o: In function `MAIN__': sandbox.for:(.text+0x1b):
undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_std' collect2: ld returned 1
exit status
```

I found an [old post](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2008-November/018266.html) that says this might be related to an old version of gcc. I'm running gfortran/gcc 4.1.2 on CentOS 5.9 Final. The mailing post suggests compiling a newer version of gcc and installing it, but I don't have root privileges on the system so I can't install newer software. I believe that on this system (it's a server at work), gfortran was installed from the repository and is kept up to date that way.

Is this error related to the version of gcc and gfortran that I'm using, or is there another problem?

#### More info

The output of `yum list | grep libgfortran` is this, if it helps:

```
libgfortran.i386                   4.1.2-54.el5            installed
libgfortran.x86_64                 4.1.2-54.el5            installed
libgfortran44.i386                 4.4.7-1.el5             base     
libgfortran44.x86_64               4.4.7-1.el5             base
```

Comment: It works for me with gfortran 4.1.2 on CentOS 5.9, gfortran 4.6.0 on Ubuntu, and gfortran 4.7.2 on Linux Mint; note that the first is the same as what you're using, or very nearly so. (You can install software from source under your home directory, but installing gcc from source is non-trivial.) The referenced [old post](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2008-November/018266.html) talks about llvm, which I'm not using; are you?

Comment: @KeithThompson I don't recall anyone mentioning anything about llvm to me, and I don't find any references to it on my system (through `locate llvm`). How can I tell if my system is using it? Is your CentOS 5.9 an x64 installation? Could that be making a difference?

Comment: Then you're *probably* not using llvm, but others might answer that better (which means that the old link probably isn't relevant). Yes, the CentOS system is 64 bits (x86_64).

Comment: @KeithThompson It's weird then. Anything else I should test in the meantime?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to check whether you've got the right packages installed. Try `yum list | grep libgfortran`. But don't count on me for more helpful information; I don't use Fortran myself.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, I'll wait and see. I went ahead and added the output of `yum list` into the question. Can't hurt.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling with `gfortran` and not `gcc`?

Comment: @Yossarian I'm using the `gfortran` command, and `whereis -b gfortran` tells me it's in `/usr/bin/gfortran`, so I don't *think* it's a symbolic link. Is there another way to tell?

Comment: Ok, looks like that isn't your problem then. Maybe try adding `-L/usr/lib -lgfortran` to your compilation command. Failing that, ask your admin to install `libgfortran44` and use that. It won't hurt your system to have two compilers installed.

Comment: I just encountered this same issue.  On Linux the problem is corrected in gfortran 4.4.7.